# I don't understand the file system structure in the Kali Linux app for Windows 11

Tags: kali-linux

I just downloaded and set up the Kali Linux app from the Microsoft app store so that I can learn how to use MOSINT. I can't figure out how to access my laptop's desktop and what the path is to cd to it. I'm very new at using Linux and get frustrated when I don't understand minute things. My user on my laptop is leaad, the lga32602 is the user Linux had me create upon installation and is the only item in the "home" path listed on this command line. What am I doing wrong??

[image]

Comment: this doesn't look like it's stellarly well set up from a Linux container point of view, which isn't your fault. But you shouldn't assume your Windows UI Desktop to be identical to what is the Desktop folder in a WSL machine. Simply two different things.

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! Please, [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086)

Comment: @MarcusMüller yeah, I do understand that. What I was asking was if there is a way I can access my Desktop.

Comment: In general you can't. Consider the thing running inside WSL2 a completely separate operating system; things have to be explecitly shared into that, and I don't know whether your specific WSL virtual machine is set up to do that. If it is, you'll probably see a *mountpoint* somewhere, making your Windows filesystem hierarchy available inside that Linux environment.

Comment: @LeaAdams can you replace the image with text copy of the commands and the errors they returned?